# upgrade joomla extension sql file doesn't gets executed

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.6

What is the difference between the usage of the install.sql file specified in extension manifest files on Joomla 1.5 and 1.6.

In 1.5, if you use method="upgrade" and the component is already installed, install.sql DOES get executed.

In 2.5, if you use method="upgrade" and the component is already installed, install.sql DOES NOT get executed.

Does anyone know if this change was intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is deliberate as from 1.6 up there is now a update tag for sql:

```
//executed when component is installed for the first time
<install folder="admin">
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/example.install.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>


//executed when component is uninstalled
<uninstall folder="admin">
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/example.uninstall.sql</file>
    </sql>
</uninstall>


//executed when the component is installed over an existing version
//or updated through the Joomla Update Manager
<update>
        <schemas>
                <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
        </schemas>
</update>
```

See the Joomla 1.6 wikipage on the manifest.xml structure [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#SQL) for more information on this

Comment: can you plz explain with more details.

Comment: When you install a module for the first time it will be marked as being 'installed' and thus follow the <install> tag. If you install and the component is already installed then the it is counted as a upgrade and thus a different sql file is needed. In this case the update tag I used above is needed